# Xamarin forms Listview and scrollview scrollbars how to set visible?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm working xamarin forms app (android target).

A view contains a scrollview.
Another view contains a listview.

In both the scrolling works great.

The problem is that scrollbar appears only on tap, when the user touch the screen with his finger. User could not understand that he has to scroll the view.

I read other posts about android native "ScrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);"

Can't find similar properties or methods in xamarain forms...
Is there a way to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to @MalokuS answer. Here is an example of what you can try.

Make a new class in your shared/PCL project. This class will contain your bindably properties you need to make your renderer.

```
namespace YourProject.Views.CustomControls
{
#region CustomScrollview

public class CustomScrollView : ScrollView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabledProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(CustomScrollView),
        true,
        BindingMode.Default,
        null);
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Horizontal scrollbar visibility
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabledProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty IsVerticalScrollbarEnabledProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(BloopyScrollView),
        false,
        BindingMode.Default,
        null);
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Vertical scrollbar visibility
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsVerticalScrollbarEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsVerticalScrollbarEnabledProperty, value); }
    }
}

#endregion
}
```

in your android project. you should have a file called "renderers". make a new class there and add folowing code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomScrollView), 
typeof(CustomScrollViewRenderer))]
namespace YourProject.Droid.Renderer
{
class CustomScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
{

    protected override async void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        this.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = ((CustomScrollView)e.NewElement).IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled;

        this.HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = ((CustomScrollView)e.NewElement).IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled;

    }

   }
```

after that you are free to use the new control in your xaml file:

```
 <CustomControls:CustomScrollView IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled = "true"
                Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
```

Hope it helps! cheers

Answer (score 0):

The 'problem' that you are referring is the default behavior of the ListView scrollbar which hides/fades when no interaction is going on the screen.

You can make custom ListView renderers for each platform: [Xamarin ListView Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/listview/)

On the Android platform specific custom renderer:

```
Control.VerticalScrollbarEnabled = true;
Control.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false causes my app to crash with 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable.mutate()' on a null object reference'

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but I had the same issue as the person asking the question and was able to get it thanks to Feddex. This answer is an extension of that answer. You can bind the property similar to what he has or you can hard code it like this below in order to always have the scrollbar be visible.

```
class MyScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        public MyScrollViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Controller != null)
            {
                this.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```