# set scrollbar visiblity to always visible in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there a way we can set scrollbar visibility to always be visible and not fade ever in xamarin forms?

In current behavior, the scrollbar fades after sometime. how do we change this to never fade. i tried to set the fade duration 10s in custom renderer but does not seem to work

```
class MyScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        public MyScrollViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Controller != null)
            {
                this.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;
                this.ScrollBarFadeDuration = 10000;
            }
        }
    }
```

i tried answers from this question but the scrollbar still fades
[Xamarin forms Listview and scrollview scrollbars how to set visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458464/xamarin-forms-listview-and-scrollview-scrollbars-how-to-set-visible)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `this.ScrollBarFadeDuration = 0;`, Such as:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView),typeof(MyScrollViewRenderer))]
namespace AppTest.Droid
{
    public class MyScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        public MyScrollViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Controller != null)
            {
                this.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;
                this.ScrollBarFadeDuration = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer with setting `ScrollBarFadeDuration` to 0. Its still the same

Comment: I tested it on both emulator and the physical device. It worked. Did you forget to add `assembly:ExportRenderer`? Or did you try to add a breakpoint to check if the `this.ScrollBarFadeDuration = 0;` triggered or not? @Aforandroid